# How do I deploy python/django which was created with virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, vps

I have learned the importance and value of using virtualenvwrapper and virtualenv on my development system.  I have an Ubuntu 16 desktop that I use for development.  Oh, btw, I don't want to use a PaaS like Heroku since I pay for VPS hosting already.

With virtualenvwrapper I just use the command workon 
and it activates the environment for myproject (where my project is some project).  My deployment environment is a VPS server with root shell access.  I run some PHP apps with apache on this, so I have installed mod_wsgi.
I have read other posts but wasn't sure about the use of virtualenv in production.  I mean I activate the environment from my shell session.

I don't know if

1. if I close my shell will the environment remain activated?
2. If so, can I have more than one activated environment on the same vps server or even on the same domain ( I put more than one domain on my production server).
3. The other option I know is to run the activate command ending with & to send it to the background.  That is somewhat of a hack though, as my web hosting provider pointed out.  It makes sense that it is problematic in that if the system was ever rebooted, I'd have to go in and re-activate the python virtualenvs.

I've taken courses on python web apps but they seem to leave out these details of moving to production.  Or they suggest a PaaS type of solution, such as Heroku.  I already pay for VPS hosting and I know this can be done.
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/11/save-on-memory-with-modwsgi-30.html

From your shell access, in your activated Python virtual environment, run the Python interpreter and enter:

```
import sys
print(sys.prefix)
```

The path it outputs is what you should then supply to the `python-home` option of the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive you are using for your daemon process group.

If you aren't using daemon process groups, especially since you are using PHP, then start using them. Also ensure you are turning off Python interpreter initialisation for embedded mode. The three posts above cover all these details.

Comment: Thanks for tips.  I am embarrassed to discover that I need to learn more about apache and the notions of embedded mode versus daemon mode.  I've been developing using php for years but didn't need to know these things.  Is my impression that developing python web apps is more complicated than php?  Or perhaps there is a difference between best practices and the easiest way to get something to work, i.e. I don't have to use a virtualenv or worry about the mode of operation but...?

Comment: The setup for Apache when running PHP applications is somewhat different to what you need to run Python applications well. Thus trying to run both at same time can cause Python site to not run well and impact overall Apache as well. The easiest way around the problem is to use daemon mode as then the PHP specific configuration doesn't cause as big an issue. You can see more details by watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6Erh7oHvns